# C# how to locate source of "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting the error `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt`.

But I cannot locate any sort of information on where it is coming from in Visual Studio in C#. In C++ I can use a call stack and it would at least tell me the last executed function.

But in C# the callstack and the function that errors out is in Program.cs on the line `Application.Run(new MainForm());`. Clicking on details reveals nothing about what the last function called was, what caused the error, etc.

How can I debug like this? How can I at least see what function caused the memory corruption?

Comment: Have you tried to enable native debugging?

Comment: Do you call native API via P/Invoke? Did it compile and run before? Can you trace the start of that error appearing to a specific change that was made?

Comment: [Application.ThreadException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception) / [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception) -- You can always set a breakpoint in Program.cs and follow the code -- A message you often get when you're handling Graphic objects in an *unsupported manner*  (when, e.g., you're using `Bitmap.LockBits` and you ignore or mismanage the Stride of the bitmap)

Comment: If you want a stack trace then you have to make the debugger stop when the exception is thrown.  Start with Tools > Options > Debugging, untick "Just My Code".   Then Debug > Windows > Exception Settings, tick "Win32 Exceptions", that makes it stop early before the CLR can catch it.  Finally Project > Properties > Debug tab, tick "Enable native code debugging", since it is likely that this mishap happened in native code.  Note that you are unlikely to see any source code when the debugger breaks, use Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols and tick the Microsoft server to get more help.

Comment: Well I think you're asking a lot for "at least see what function caused the memory corruption" - if my debugger had that we'd all be very happy. But as @HansPassant has pointed out, you can at least see what function "discovered" the memory corruption.

Comment: Hans Passant
  I already have all of these selected, and Just My code is unticked, how can I see the function that "discovered" the memory corruption? It still stops on `Application.Run(new MainForm());`